# How to insert text line by line in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I insert text from a variable so that each item in a variable prints onto a new line if the line is already taken in tkinter?

My code is

```
 variable = list.get(0, END)
 item = Label(root, text = variable)
 item.pack()
```

My current result is:
[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ3h5.png)

How I want it to look like:
[needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz2Zp.png)

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`variable` is a tuple of strings, so use `string.join()` to concat those strings into one string:

```
item = Label(root, text='\n'.join(variable))
```